# Excel Addinの｢HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINEに登録されているOfficeアドインの接続状態は変更できません｡｣について

Tags: c#, excel

Excel2013のAddinを作り､Excel2013上で正しくリボンとして動作するところまで完了しました｡

しかし､別の要望として､Excel2007or2010でも動作することが必要になり､dllを変更して､vsto自体のビルドは通り､setup.exeでインストールもできたのですが､COMアドインの有効がうまくいきません｡

ちなみに有効にしようとすると､添付画像のようなメッセージがでます｡

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

内容がまったくわからず､お手上げ状態です｡
どなたか､ご教授お願いします｡